# I'm trying to create a responsive design that adjusts to different screen sizes using CSS media queries. Can someone help me figure out what's wrong

Tags: media-queries

`` `@media screen and (max-width: 768px) { ``
`.my-element {`
`font-size: 16px;`
`}`
`}`

`@media screen and (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 1024px) {`
`.my-element {`
`font-size: 18px;`
`}`
`}`

`@media screen and (min-width: 1024px) {`
`.my-element {`
`font-size: 20px;`
`}`
`` }` ``
I was expecting the font size of .my-element to adjust based on the screen size, but it doesn't seem to be working. What am I doing wrong?"

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that the .my-element class is being applied to the correct element in your HTML. If it's not, the font size won't adjust as expected.
Check that there are no other styles elsewhere in your CSS that might be overriding the font size changes made by the media queries.
Try adding the !important declaration to the font-size property in each media query to ensure that it takes priority over other styles. However, it's generally not recommended to use !important unless it's necessary to do so.
Verify that your browser window size is within the range specified by one of the media queries. If it's not, the font size won't adjust until the screen size meets the criteria of one of the media queries.

Comment: Do you know any documents to read about this subjects?

Comment: I found this source that helped me. [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_media_queries/Using_media_queries)